# Touch down / touch up in IOS using xcode and swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimageview, ontouchlistener

I need to implement a thumb print scanner in swift with xcode. I  found the gesture recogniser but I am missing the point where I can react to the "onTouchDown" and "onTouchUp" events.

the underlying object is an UIImageView. I am quite new to this and I can't find proper documentation on this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current iOS devices, the following hardware is supported:

- A screen that is multi-touch aware.
- A home button that is able to read thumb-prints.

Therefore its not possible to implement a thumb-print scanner on a UIImageView or any UIView. You can however respond to touches, multi-touches, track acceleration, speed, movement, etc.

**Responding to touch events:**

There's a few ways to respond to touch events.

**UIButton:**

You could add a UIButton as a subview or your view. Be sure to size it to take up the parent view's bounds. Then use `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod) controlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`

**Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer:**

Add a UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
_panHandler = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
    action:@selector(panHandle:)];

- (void)panHandle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
{
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       //do something
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        //do something
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

**Lowest level / most flexible / more work:**

In your UIView sub-class override:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
}
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but the mentioned "onTouchDown" and "onTouchUp" events must exist, somehow?

Comment: They do at various levels of abstraction, starting with UIView, to gesture recognizers, to pre-built touch aware components, like UIButton.

Comment: Oops. . . sorry for answering in Objective-C. Is that ok? Can convert to Swift if you like.

Comment: thanks Jasper, I found out before that this probabbly is the best solution! implementing this functionality with the button and xcode is quite easy. Thanks four your help, though!

Comment: It can be hard to find the info at first but once you build your Cocoa-fu you'll be flying along :)